# Select2.js with multiple tags and not dropdown icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, dropdown

In Select2.js, by default there is a select dropdown box and a dropdown icon to make it intuitive for the user that it is a dropdown and not just an input box.

When we make the select dropdown box with multiple tags enabled, the dropdown box looks more like an input text box. basically the dropdown icon is missing.

Please refer - https://select2.github.io/examples.html

So to add the dropdown icon, i could add it in the select2.js file. But i think it is not a good idea. Any other easier or better way to get the dropdown icon for multi - select select2 js dropdown box?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, when you are using tags, it will become an input box. Select is only for single selection, and Textbox is for multiple selection, a.k.a. tags. `:)` This is by design.

The best alternate is to use placeholders, which can tell the users that it is a multiselect autosuggest:

```
$(element).select2({
  placeholder: "Start typing..."
});
```

Comment: You are right! i saw that. But now requirement is to have the icon with multi selection. what's the approach.

Comment: @anandpatil Hack `select2.js` like you already said. You can also fake it using CSS, but both are not recommended and you know the reason.